# problem Mysqldump from a bat file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, mysql

I have one bat file on windows7, for backup several tables from my database, like this:

```
"c:\Gesticom\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uuser -ppsswd bbdddc [clientes, usuarios, proyectos, proveedores, areas_negocio, costes] --opt > tmp.sql
```

When I execute this bat I have seen that the code is changed for something like this:

```
"c:\Gesticom\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uuser -ppsswd bbdddc [clientes, usuarios, proyectos, proveedores, areas_negocio, costes] --opt 1>tmp.sql
```

Someone knows why appears this number "1"? With it the mysqldump command doesn't work :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a canonical representation of the command for `cmd`. It doesn't affect anything that is executed and, in fact, is identical to the command you provided.

It merely says that stream 1 (stdout) is redirected into `tmp.sql`. If your dump does not work, then it wouldn't have worked before, either.

Comment: In that case, are you using characters that need to be treated differently in batch files, such as `%` somewhere?

Comment: Oh! The problem is on the "[]" I have erased them and the script works like a charm